# Are Sybase datetime fields supported in PolyBase exernal tables?

Tags: odbc, sybase, sap-ase, polybase

I'm working with PolyBase on SQL Server 2022. I have some tables with type "datetime NULL" on Sybase ASE 16.

When declaring an external table e.g.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE SYBASESCHEMA.SomeTable
(
    [SomeNiceTime] DATETIME NULL
)
WITH (LOCATION = N'SomeNiceDatabase.dbo.SomeTable', DATA_SOURCE = SYBASE_DS);
```

I receive an error message like the following one:

```
105083;The following columns in the user defined schema are incompatible with the external table schema for table 'SomeTable': 'SomeNiceTime' failed to be reflected with the error: 'The detected ODBC SQL_TYPE 11 is not supported for external generic tables.'
```

Does anyone know how this could be resolved?

Comment: as a fly on the wall ... Sybase/SAP ASE 16 has several date and time datatypes - `date`, `time`, `smalldatetime`, `datetime`, `bigdatetime`, `bigtime` - can you confirm your ASE column is in fact defined with the `datetime` datatype?

Comment: @markp-fuso, it is indeed a datetime. I've checked through Sybase Central

Comment: After 2 support sessions with Microsoft the conclusion is that the conversion from Sybase datetime format to MS SQL Server datetime format is not supported.